# When will lettuce create a connection

Tags: connection, lettuce

As we know ,many threads can use  one connection at the same time, but when will lettuce  create  a new connection ，what‘s the trigger conditions

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: it's when you call the connect method.

https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/

```
public static <K,V> StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnection<K,V> connect(RedisClient 
redisClient, RedisCodec<K,V> codec, Iterable<RedisURI> redisURIs)

Open a new connection to a Redis Master-Slave server/servers using the supplied 
RedisURI and the supplied codec to encode/decode keys.
```